# Node-sass is not auto-compiling in latest node/express

Tags: node.js, express, sass

Using node (0.10.15) and express (3.3.4), along with the latest node-sass, and I can't get my scss files to compile. My app.js file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , sass = require('node-sass');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(
  sass.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/public/sass',
    dest: __dirname + '/public',
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
  })
);

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

What am I missing to get sass to auto-compile?

If it matters, I'm using supervisor to monitor changes.

Comment: Did it work previously / with other versions?

Comment: Nope. I've since moved over to grunt-contrib-compass to get this working.

Answer (score 8):

Middlewares are executed in the order they are attached to the app. The `node-sass` middleware only compiles `scss` files to `css`, it does not serve them. The `static` middleware is able to serve the compiled `css` files, however, it can’t do so as long as the `css` files are not compiled yet. If you switch `static` and `sass` middlewares, everything should work as expected:

```
app.use(
  sass.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/public/sass',
    dest: __dirname + '/public',
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
  })
);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Now the following happens when you request `/style.css`:

1. `sass` notices a request for a `css` file. If the dest file (`__dirname + '/public' + '/style.css'`) is up-to-date, it does nothing. Otherwise, it looks for the src file (`__dirname + '/public/sass' + '/style.scss'`) and compiles it, if it exists.
2. `static` notices a request for a static asset. If the requested file (`path.join(__dirname, 'public') + '/style.css'`) does exist, it is served.

Answer (score 0):

I also had serious problems setting this up with Koa (koa.js) and koa-sass. Eventually I figured out the problems. node-sass is 'too clever' for it's own good:

```
app.use(sass({
    src: __dirname + '/public/sass',
    dest: __dirname + '/public/css',
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
    prefix:  '/stylesheets'
}));
```

I was getting a 500 when it tried to access `/public/sass/stylesheets/styles.css`- but I didn't have 'stylesheets' in my path: My html template file was looking at `/stylesheets/styles.css` so I had to remove the prefix with `prefix: '/stylesheets'`.

Next I had a problem with the scss file - I had accidentally copied an old .styl file and it was trying to use nib - which I found after discovering the debug: true setting.

As soon as I replaced it with a valid css or scss file it compiled and rendered using koa-static.

Although this is a koa-sass issue, koa-sass just wraps node-sass with a generator so it belongs here (IMO).